# Cordova Media plugin not calling success or error callback

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I cannot get the Cordova Media to work at all on Android, I can instantiate a Media object but neither the success nor the error callback is ever called.

I am using Apache Cordova 5.1.1 with the Media plugin 1.0.1 on Android 5.1.1, in the deviceready event handler I have the following code:

```
var src = 'https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3';
console.log('Media object: ' + Media);
this.media = new Media(src, function () {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
}, function (error) {
    console.log('ERROR');
});
console.log('Media instance: ' + this.media);
```

which produces the following output:

```
I/chromium( 1953): [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "Media object: function (src, successCallback, errorCallback, statusCallback) {
I/chromium( 1953):     argscheck.checkArgs('sFFF', 'Media', arguments);
I/chromium( 1953):     this.id = utils.createUUID();
I/chromium( 1953):     mediaObjects[this.id] = this;
I/chromium( 1953):     this.src = src;
I/chromium( 1953):     this.successCallback = successCallback;
I/chromium( 1953):     this.errorCallback = errorCallback;
I/chromium( 1953):     this.statusCallback = statusCallback;
I/chromium( 1953):     this._duration = -1;
I/chromium( 1953):     this._position = -1;
I/chromium( 1953):     exec(null, this.errorCallback, "Media", "create", [this.id, this.src]);
I/chromium( 1953): }", source: file:///android_asset/www/scripts/index.js (6)
I/chromium( 1953): [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Media instance: [object Object]", source: file:///android_asset/www/scripts/index.js (12)
```

so the Media object is clearly there and an instance is created, but then nothing ever happens, neither callback function is run. Am I doing something wrong or am I hitting a bug?

Comment: have you tried to uninstall/reinstall the plugin? (sometimes plugins get corrupted)